# Click event gets triggered when navigating with the Tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a little issue with a click bind on a button which gets triggered when I navigate with the TAB key through some fields.

I'm developing a Chrome Extension, so I'm working on an already-created page. I have a `table` which is managed totally with some page-internal Javascript code.
In my extension I have to add a button on every row of this table, which I have. When the user clicks on this button it has to retrieve the columns of the related row and paste them in a textbox.

In these table rows you can go column to column pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key on the keyboard. I just noticed that the copy-paste of the columns (which is bound to the `click` event of the button) gets triggered randomly when I navigate the columns pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> where I select the fields.

```js
$('.addActivity').click(function(e) {
  let row = $(this).closest('tr');
  let string = $(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Created"]').text() + ' - ' + $(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Primary_Owned_By"]').html() + ' - ' + ($(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Type"]').find('a').length ? $(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Type"]').find('a').html() : $(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Type"]').find('input').val()) + ' - ' + ($(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Description"] textarea').length ? $(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Description"] textarea').val() : $(row).find('td[id*="s_3_l_Description"]').find('div').html());
  console.log('ADDED ACTIVITY ON CLICK');

  $('#sh_status').val(string + '\n' + $('#sh_status').val().trim());
  if (settings.activityTracker.autoSave) 
    _forceSiebelUpdate();
  else 
    _toSave();

  console.log(e.which);

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

The `.addActivity` class are the buttons. Do you have any idea why this gets triggered this way?

Comment: Pressing the return key on a clickable element raises a `click` event; this is expected behaviour. It's used by people who cannot navigate using the mouse, or prefer not to

Comment: I have to precise that I don't navigate on my button with the TAB, so the ENTER is not directly triggering it.